# Dynamic select box change event not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm having a drop down which is coming dynamically :-

Controller :-

```
function get_model_by_make()
{
    $str = $this->Comparecars_model->get_model_by_make();
    echo $str;      
}
```

Model :-

```
function get_model_by_make()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    model
                WHERE
                    makeid = '".$_POST['make_id']."'
                ";

        $result = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();

        $str = '<select style="width:130px;" class="compare_model_name">
                    <option value="">--Select Model--</option>
                ';

        foreach($result as $result)
        {
            $str .= '<option value="'.$result['model_id'].'">'.$result['model_name'].'</option>';       
        }

        $str .= '</select> - ';
         return $str;
    }
```

the above code display selectbox with class name `compare_model_name`. Now I'm trying to add change event to this class name but it doesn't work:-

```
$(document).ready(function()
{    
    $('.compare_model_name').on("change",function()
    {
            alert(); // It does not alert
    }); 
});
```

Also console is not showing any error.

**Edit :-**

View :-

```
  <select style="width:130px;" id="drpMake1" name="drpMake1" class="compare_make_name">
        <option value="">--Select Make--</option>
                <?php
                    foreach($make as $make)
                    {
                        echo '<option value="'.$make['make_id'].'">'.$make['make_name'].'</option>';
                    }
                ?>    

    </select> - <!-- On selecting it will bring new selectbox which is shown below -->


    <span id="model_span">
        <select style="width:130px;" class="aspNetDisabled" disabled="disabled" id="drpModel1" name="drpModel1">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">--Select Model--</option>

        </select> 

</span>
```

Comment: try to place jquery code inside `$(document).ready(function()....code  });` . and why two event for onchange? your calling from javascript `.on(change)` and also calling  `onchange="rakesh(this)"` in your dom

Comment: @Roopendra thanks for your reply sorry it was typo now i have edited my code

Comment: did you try `bind`? like `$(".compare_model_name").bind("change", function(e) {});`

Comment: Which version of jquery you are using? and also try @kumar_v suggestion.

Comment: @Roopendra im using jquery 1.9.1 also i have tried bind event also but it is not working

Comment: @kumar_v I used bind event but still not working

Comment: Do you want to create `select` only through ajax? Why can't you create `select` without options in page load itself. then you can load options via ajax. That's it.

Comment: @kumar_v can you provide me some example? how can I do this using  my code ?

Comment: Add your view code then I can post answer easily

Comment: ok @kumar_v Ill do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you need to place new dropdown before `<span id="model_span">`
Then add below line in your view file.

```
<select style="width:130px;" class="compare_model_name">

</select>
```

Then in your ajax success, add options like

```
$(".compare_model_name").html(options);
```

In your model function `get_model_by_make`, remove `<select>` and `</select>` lines.
Then assign your `$str = ' <option value="">--Select Model--</option>';`

**Note:** Do not do this kind of `echo` in model. Instead, you have to do everything in controller.Model should have only DB Kind of coding. Not echo or logical part. Follow the MVC Structure :-)